# Do active filters count as amplifers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, filter, active-filter

Can we consider active filters to be amplifers?

If we use the folowing active filter design, and adjust R1 and R2 correctly that the gain is set to 10 for example, does the output signal comes out both filtered and amplifed?

[image]

Can we say that this desgin merge two blocks, a filter stage and an amplifer stage?

I'd be happy to highlight any flaws for this design.

Comment: That's not an active filter. It's a passive filter followed by buffer/amplifier.

Comment: See https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_5.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the output will be both filtered and amplified in said case.

This design could also be viewed as a passive filter followed by an amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

That's a passive filter followed by an amplifier.

A more general active filter (such as a second order [Sallen&Key filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sallen%E2%80%93Key_topology) section - see figure 1) takes feedback from the output of the amplifier into the filter network.

And in this case, if you change the gain as in your schematic, you also change the feedback fraction which changes the frequency response. (You can compensate for this by e.g. reducing the feedback by increasing the feedback resistor or reducing the feedback capacitor when you increase the gain)

So the answer is yes, but it's not quite that simple.

Most filter design programs will let you choose a gain as well as a frequency response, and handle the complexity for you.

Answer (score 0):

With just resistors and capacitors it's theoretically impossible to make a filter whose poles aren't confined to the negative real axis of the s plane. If an amplifier is added to the mix in the right way the poles aren't necessarily restricted to the real axis - they can occur in complex conjugate pairs. If they do the circuit is called an active filter. There are many popular configurations that do just that. When the pole pairs are close to the imaginary axis the circuit is said to exhibit resonance and can be used to make a very narrow bandpass filter or a high pass or low pass filter with sharp cutoff.